# check localStorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a function where a user can vote on a list of items.
When click on the vote-button i set a localStorage object like this

```
localStorage['vote' + id] = 'true';
```

When the user comes to the page again a want to check if he can vote or not. eg. if he already have voted once i want to hide the vote-button or something. Right now i have this check in the click function for vote. But i want to do the check asap when the user visits the site.

Anyone know how to do that?

In my click the check looks like this. But i want to do the check as first thing when the website opens.

```
        if(localStorage['vote' + id] == 'true') {
            $(container).find("span").html("already voted")
            return;
        }
```

Comment: So why don't you check that on $(document).ready(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the:

```
if (localStorage['vote' + id] == 'true') {
    // Don't let them vote
}
```

...code in a script tag at the end of the HTML (just before the `</body>` tag). (This is [where your script tags should be in general anyway](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).) Then you'll know the container exists and you can update the span.

E.g.:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- ...the usual header stuff ... -->
<body>
<!-- ...your body content... -->
<script src="/path/to/your/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

...where the check exists in the relevant script file. (Or you can put the script inline, of coruse.)

Comment: Thanks. But when i do that the ID gets undefined. This code runs in an own js-file with an init(), render() etc. And the id gets set on a click. I want tp check that id in the init().

Comment: @user3122094: Well yes, obviously you need to make sure you're setting `id` correctly. If `id` is a page-wide value, that's fine. If it's specific to each question, you'll need a loop.

Comment: Yes, i gets set. I just dont manage to retrieve it in mi init. How would that be done? can i loop it in init or how do you mean?

Comment: @user3122094: Where does this `id` come from? Nothing in your question says. If (for example) it's stored as a data- attribute on the elements you're clicking, you'd query those elements, loop through them, and use that attribute.

Comment: Hi, yes it comes from a data-attribute on the items i click on. How would i do that?

Comment: @user3122094: `$("div[data-id]").each(function() { var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); /* Use id here */ });`

Comment: Thanks! How would i do the check?

Comment: @user3122094: I suggest you step back from what you're currently doing and work through some basic JavaScript and jQuery tutorials.